# Why does my three.js canvas masking not work?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, mask

I'm trying to reproduce example of Szenia Zadvornykh presented here https://medium.com/@Zadvorsky/webgl-masking-composition-75b82dd4cdfd

His demo is based on three.js r80, so I referenced r101 and tried to remove most of unrelated parts, and just have scene with grid and png mask on top.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/y2kt3Lrf/

Having commented `// composer.addPass(maskPass)` the grid shows up. But it does not seem like `uniform sampler2D tDiffuse` has the output of render pass.

I expect to see the grid helper and underlying HTML content under the canvas, where mask makes canvas transparent.

**UPDATE**, working now, thanks to @Mugen87: http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/y2kt3Lrf/
[image: three.js masking canvas transparency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch of files in your fiddle. If I use the latest version of `three.js` and the respective post processing classes, your code works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/pk24zby7/

`three.js` has deprecated the `renderTarget` and `forceClear` parameter from `WebGLrenderer.render()` with `R102`. When the change was done, it was necessary to change many files in the examples directory in order to avoid warnings and even breakage. So using the latest post-processing classes with an older `three.js` version does not work.

Since the change is listed in the [release note](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r102), I suggest you read the respective PRs for more details.