# Three js postProcessing solution with transparency

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, post-processing

I discovered that solution to create postporcessing effects with three.js :
https://medium.com/@luruke/simple-postprocessing-in-three-js-91936ecadfb7
(made by Luigi De Rosa)

It's a great way to do it. Unfortunately I can't manage to add transparency in my final renderer. Should I add a transparency component inside my postprocessing fragment shader ?

```
const fragmentShader = `precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D uScene;
    uniform vec2 uResolution;
    uniform float uTime;

    void main() {
        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy;
        vec3 color = vec3(uv, 1.0);

        //simple distortion effect
        uv.y += sin(uv.x*30.0+uTime*10.0)/40.0;
        uv.x -= sin(uv.y*10.0-uTime)/40.0;

        color = texture2D(uScene, uv).rgb;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

    }
`;
```

Thank you

**EDIT 1 :**

I added the attribute `transparent:true` to the `RawShaderMaterial`.

I changed the format of the new `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` by `THREE.RGBAFormat` instead of `THREE.RGBFormat`.

I also added those lines at the end of my fragment shader :

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
vec4 tex = texture2D( uScene, uv );
if(tex.a < 0.0) {
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

But I still doesn't see through my canvas

**EDIT 2 :**

Here's a snippet with the postProcessing class

```js
    let renderer, camera, scene, W = window.innerWidth, H = window.innerHeight, geometry, material, mesh;

    initWebgl();
    function initWebgl(){

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( W, H );
        document.querySelector('.innerCanvas').appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-W/H/2, W/H/2, 1/2, -1/2, -0.1, 0.1);
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
       
        geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(0.5, 0.5);
        material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry , material );
        scene.add(mesh);

      
    } 

    function rafP(){
        requestAnimationFrame(rafP);

        // renderer.render(scene, camera);
        post.render(scene, camera);

    }
    
    
    const vertexShader = `precision highp float;
        attribute vec2 position;
        void main() {
          // Look ma! no projection matrix multiplication,
          // because we pass the values directly in clip space coordinates.
          gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0, 1.0);
        }`;

    const fragmentShader = `precision highp float;
        uniform sampler2D uScene;
        uniform vec2 uResolution;
        uniform float uTime;

        void main() {
            vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy;
            vec3 color = vec3(uv, 1.0);

            uv.y += sin(uv.x*20.0)/10.0;

            color = texture2D(uScene, uv).rgb;
            
            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

            vec4 tex = texture2D( uScene, uv );
            // if(tex.a - percent < 0.0) {
            if(tex.a < 0.0) {
                gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
                //or without transparent = true use
                // discard; 
            }
        
        }`;

    //PostProcessing
    class PostFX {
        constructor(renderer) {
            this.renderer = renderer;
            this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // three.js for .render() wants a camera, even if we're not using it :(
            this.dummyCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera();
            this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

            // Triangle expressed in clip space coordinates
            const vertices = new Float32Array([
              -1.0, -1.0,
              3.0, -1.0,
              -1.0, 3.0
            ]);

            this.geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 2));

            this.resolution = new THREE.Vector2();
            this.renderer.getDrawingBufferSize(this.resolution);

            this.target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.resolution.x, this.resolution.y, {
                format: THREE.RGBAFormat,  //THREE.RGBFormat
                stencilBuffer: false,
                depthBuffer: true
            });

            this.material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
                fragmentShader,
                vertexShader,
                uniforms: {
                    uScene: { value: this.target.texture },
                    uResolution: { value: this.resolution }
                },
                transparent:true
            });

            // TODO: handle the resize -> update uResolution uniform and this.target.setSize()

            this.triangle = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
            // Our triangle will be always on screen, so avoid frustum culling checking
            this.triangle.frustumCulled = false;
            this.scene.add(this.triangle);
        }

        render(scene, camera) {
            this.renderer.setRenderTarget(this.target);
            this.renderer.render(scene, camera);
            this.renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.dummyCamera);

            console.log(this.renderer);
        }
    }

    post = new PostFX(renderer); 
    rafP();
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#00F;
 }
 .innerCanvas{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.js"></script>

<div class="innerCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. `gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);` has a very noticeable alpha value of `1.0`. You're going to have to modify that value if you want transparency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I noticed it. I just edited my question : I try to play with the `gl_FragColor.a` attribute of my fragment shader.

Comment: @MichaëlGarciaIt's still not clear if you are correctly altering gl_FragColor.a looking by the code you posted. Can you post a live example that can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I just updated my question and added a snippet with that behaviour.

Comment: maybe this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393149/why-does-my-three-js-canvas-masking-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Alpha channel, 0 means fully transparent and 1 means fully opaque.

The only thing you need, in this case, is to pass `gl_FragColor` the result from your texture sample. You don't even need to worry about its value.

`gl_FragColor = texture2D(uScene, uv);`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxb10n3o/)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much, it's working now. I noticed one last issue : I now have a little border all around my mesh. I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Refrain from editing your question too much. As it stands, the current problem doesn't seem to be related with the old one. Mark this answer as correct if it solves your original problem, and consider creating a new question for the current problem.